# set value to a input and grab it on change or keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the html code bellow. The id `foo` input taking a text then cloning to another input id `doo`. As you can see in jquery code i am simply passing the value from foo to doo. But my problem is when i try to get value of `doo` on second part of code in jquery i dont get updated value of `doo`. Thing is that if i write input in `foo` then it virtually displays in `doo` but in real this not changing i think. So what i want is- when i pass input in `foo` it will also trigger in `doo` value. Since i am also updating `doo` from `foo`. Ask question if you want to know anything more. Thanks in advance

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/744945/)

Jquery:

```
$("#foo").keyup(function () {
         $('#doo').val($(this).val());

        });



$("#doo").on("change paste keyup", function () {
            var tryGetNewValue = $('#doo').val();
            console.log(tryGetNewValue);
        });
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value=""><br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="doo" value=""><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better use deligate function of jquery. Both function change both input values.

```
 $(document).on("input paste keyup","#doo,#foo", function (e) {
     $("#foo").val($(this).val());
     $("#doo").val($(this).val());
     var tryGetNewValue = $(this).val();
     console.log(tryGetNewValue);
 });
```

You can even get same thing like below to

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "#doo, $foo", "input paste keyup", function(e) {
  $("#foo").val($(this).val());
  $("#doo").val($(this).val());
  var tryGetNewValue = $(this).val();
  console.log(tryGetNewValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the functions are running at the same time and the value of doo hasn’t changed in time for the function. I would change your js code to this:

```
$("#foo").keyup(function () {
     $('#doo').val($(this).val());
 var tryGetNewValue = $('#doo').val();
        console.log(tryGetNewValue);
    });



$("#doo").on("paste keyup", function () {
        var tryGetNewValue = $('#doo').val();
        console.log(tryGetNewValue);
    });
```

And then obviously run whatever you would run in both places where you have the var tryGetNewValue running

Comment: you are copying the `var tryGetNewValue = $('#doo').val()` in both function. But this is not my goal at all. I want to grab current value of `doo` no matter who input it like input from `foo` or input menually in `doo`

Comment: That is why I took the change listener off of the second function. This way, when you change doo manually it will run the function with what you changed it too, but when you change foo, it will run the same function through only the foo function, not the doo function, working the same way although taking a slightly different path.

Answer (score 1):

The change event does not get triggered because only input directly from the user into the element can set it off (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

As for a way to allow this to work, you can use a function for each event like so:

```
$("#foo").keyup(function () {
   $('#doo').val($(this).val());
   changeEvent();
});

$("#doo").on("change paste keyup", function () {
   changeEvent()
}); 

function changeEvent(){
   var tryGetNewValue = $('#doo').val();
   console.log(tryGetNewValue);
}
```